# Copying with macro overwrites numberformat in unaffected cells

Tags: vba, excel

In my work, on a daily basis, I am using a macro I wrote years ago. In a nutshell, this macro adds items from a daily generated report to a file with certain tables. The code i use for copying:
`.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wsReq.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`
This has worked fine for years, but last week, all of a sudden, it started causing something strange. 
Right after this row quoted above is executed for the first time during that run, all blank cells are formatted to have a number format of "$ ##0" (dollar sign, space, value, no decimals)

The source file has everything in "general" format, the destination file has the format of either general or number (definitely not currency), yet when this step is executed, the numbers appear in the wrong format.
Even 10-digit IDs now look like that...

ID in the source file: 45346345
After pasting it in the destination file: $ 45 346 345

The bigger issue is that this is the format, like i said, in blank cells too. Let's say my destination table has a used range of 345 rows. After the copy-paste, starting from Row 346, up until the very bottom, all cells (in all of the empty rows) now have a currency format. Even if i delete all rows, starting at 346 -- after the copy-paste, they will, once again, have the same currency format.

I narrowed it down to the line above, that is where that change happens.
It IS possible to change the format afterwards, which i now do within the same macro, but we're talking about a table with 140-ish columns, i don't wanna add formatter lines for all 140 cells...
Especially since it happens on EVERY sheet of the file. All blank cells on every sheet are formatted to currency.

Like i said, this has just started happening. When i first saw this, the file was last modified by myself, and i hadn't done anything to it that i think could cause this.

---

*Solution: It took me ages and a lot of frustration, but finally solved it. Ribbon -> Home -> Styles -> right click on Normal, then hit Modify. There, change the Default number format. It must have been one of those cases when you accidentally hit a number of keys at the same time and then that changes some settings, and you only notice anything later on.*

Comment: As it turns out, this happens when i manually copy data, too.

Comment: It took me ages and a lot of frustration, but finally solved it.
Ribbon -> Home -> Styles -> right click on Normal, then hit Modify.
There, change the Default number format.
It must have been one of those cases when you accidentally hit a number of keys at the same time and then that changes some settings, and you only notice anything later on.

Comment: You should add that as an answer.